# Display checkbox checked dynamically in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to display the checkbox checked if value is 1 in database as the page load in my new ionic framework application.

I use `ng-model` and `ng-init` as below:

```
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="c.checked" ng-init="c.checked = new1"   ng-click="clickmenu();"  style="width: 28px;"> Menu
```

And in JavaScript file:

```
 $scope.c = {};
 $scope.new1 = true;
```

But the checkbox remains unchecked.
I referred this link but is not working

http://plnkr.co/edit/OaKnDNRSVoK18IbpDlTk?p=preview

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ng-checked`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) instead ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w1G6XhNpa5MTKvrg7VgP?p=preview)):

```
<label>Check me to check both: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master"></label><br/>
<input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="master" aria-label="Slave input">
```

Comment: I want my check box to be checked if it has value in database as 1 and that to after page load . I dont understant the method mentioned above . can u pls make it clear

Comment: Cannot find where you check `value in database as 1` in your code. Suppose you need to use `$http` service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ....On page load i will check in my app's sqlite database whether the field value is 1 or 0 ..if its 1 i need to display checkbox  as checked . i dont want to use service ...is there any other way ???

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this method, It worked for me

```
<label class="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="registrationForm.checkbox" required="required">
 </label>
```

In your controller

```
if(!$scope.registrationForm.checkbox)
{     
$ionicPopup.alert({
      template: "Please accept the Terms and Conditions",
      title: 'Error',
});
 return false;
}
```